# .css().animate() not working?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I wanted to highlight an element with this:

```
$('input.step:last').css('background','#003').animate({'background':'#fff'},300);
```

But it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cpwmm/

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need the `JQuery.Color` plugin (part of `jquery-ui`). Then do,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input.step:last')
     .css({'backgroundColor':'#003'})
    .animate({'backgroundColor':'#fff'},300);
})​
```

Answer (score 6):

To animate colors you will need to add the jQuery Animate Colors plugin.

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Then, you should use:

```
$('input.step:last').css('background-color','#003')
                    .animate({'background-color':'#fff'},300);
```

Mind the difference that you should animate the 'background-color' property rather than the 'background' one.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cpwmm/7/

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery [can’t animate colors](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties). You can use the [`jQuery.color()` plugin, found here,](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to give it that ability.